# Model State Object and User State Object

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-framework-1.x

User State Object sets its value in session that's way we can get value from any where but model state object which is nothing more then a Jobject which doesn't use session to store value then how model state variable remain it's value when we come back later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model is not intended to save anything (I am not talking about model cache), because that is a job for session. That is why model very often uses User State to retrieve some data form the session, for example the states of different filters.

Comment: that means model state variables will be lost as soon as we navigate to different view ( that using other model) .? but if we want to save values for cross view we Have to use user State Variable.? **and yes Thanks**

Comment: Yes you need to use a User State to save the values across different views.